# How can I send a put request without the key value from the entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to update a user and add a password to a new column that was created in the database as that password will be encrypted. However I'm getting the following error and it is not being sent as an update on the row but as a new row in the database, I checked and the majority does the update with the .save(method) in the repository but it updates the object not adds a new row:

```
2022-10-26 12:50:37.648  INFO 13732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.ssc.test.cb3.service.UserService     
: Fetching user htorres
Existent user: User(serie=5, username=htorres, name=Herney Torres, password=htorres, 
profile=1, email=, status=false, passwordc=null, roles=[Role(serie=1, name=ROLE_USER)])
2022-10-26 12:50:37.793  INFO 13732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.ssc.test.cb3.service.UserService     
: Saving new user Herney Torres to the database
2022-10-26 12:50:38.064  WARN 13732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] 
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2022-10-26 12:50:38.064 ERROR 13732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] 
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de 
unicidad «usuario_login_key»
Detail: Ya existe la llave (login)=(htorres).
```

The last message in Detail says:  There is already a key (login) = (htorres).

How can I send the request without the primary key "login" which is the username? I tried to not include it in the request in postman but it returns the error `ERROR 13732 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper`   : ERROR: The value null for the column <> violates the restriction not null`, I checked that with lists it is possible to use the .remove() to not include the primary key as in the following resource, but not sure how in my architecture:

[SpringRest with arrayLists](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/spring-rest-put-actualizando-registros/)

This is my class:

```
package com.ssc.test.cb3.controller;


import com.ssc.test.cb3.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

/**
 * Class to handle REST services and APIs for the Customer's class
 *
 * @author ssc
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/users")
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @PutMapping("/updateUser/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") String username, @RequestBody User user){
        User existentUser = userService.getUser(username);
        System.out.println("Existent user: " + existentUser);
        existentUser.setPasswordc(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPasswordc()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createUser(user));   
    }

}
```

The service class:

package com.ssc.test.cb3.service;

```
import com.ssc.test.cb3.model.Role;
import com.ssc.test.cb3.model.User;
import com.ssc.test.cb3.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.ssc.test.cb3.repository.UserRepository;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * Class to prepare the services to be dispatched upon request regarding Customers. 
 * @author ssc
 */

@Service 
@Transactional 
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);  // details from user loaded by getting the username
        if(user == null){
            log.error("User not found in the database");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found in the database");
        } else {
            log.info("User found in the database: {}", username);
        }
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> { 
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        });
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    /**
     *  Method to get details from a user by the username
     * @param username key that helps to identify the user we want to retrieve from the database
     * @return the user details. 
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException 
     */
    public User getUserDetailsByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);  // details from user loaded by getting the username
        if(user == null){
            log.error("User not found in the database by that username");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found in the database by that username");
        } else {
            log.info("User found in the database: {}", username);
        }
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param id
     * @return 
     */
    public User getUser(String username){
        log.info("Fetching user {}", username);
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }


    /**
     * Functionality to create a new user
     * @param user receives an objet User to be saved on the database
     * @return the action of saving the user in the database. 
     */
    public User createUser(User user){
        log.info("Saving new user {} to the database", user.getName());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setPasswordc(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPasswordc()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    } 

}
```

My repository class:

```
package com.ssc.test.cb3.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.ssc.test.cb3.model.User;

/**
 * Class that extends to the repository for database management queries with table Usuario
 * @author ssc
 */

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

And finally my user entity class:

```
package com.ssc.test.cb3.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

/**
 * Class that models the entity User as table of the database
 * @author cardo
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int serie;

    @Column(name = "login")  
    private String username;   // Username...

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String name;

    private String password;

    @Column(name = "perfil")
    private int profile;

    private String email;

    @Column(name = "activo")
    private boolean status;

    private String passwordc;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something fishy with what you're doing.

First of all in the controller you're doing this

```
        User existentUser = userService.getUser(username);
        System.out.println("Existent user: " + existentUser);
        existentUser.setPasswordc(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPasswordc()));
```

but you don't save the `existingUser` so the changes won't persist.

After that, you create a new user using the payload

```
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createUser(user)); 

    public User createUser(User user){
        log.info("Saving new user {} to the database", user.getName());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setPasswordc(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPasswordc()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

but it seems the payload contains information of an existing user. What i would do would be something like

```
    public User createOrUpdateUser(User userPayload){
        log.info("Saving user {} to the database", user.getName());

         User dbUser = getUser(user.getUsername());

        if(isNull(dbUser)) {
          dbUser = ..logic for creating a new user
        } else {
          // logic to update the db user properties using the userPayload
          dbUser.set
        }

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Also i would reconsider what you're doing here as these can be split up in POST for creation of a user and PUT for updating a user.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is you are not passing the existing User object to the repository save method. The primary key in the database is the autogenerated ID, not the username. When you first retrieve the user into the `existentUser` variable, this is the attached entity which has the primary key set. Any updates you make to this entity inside the scope of a database transaction would automatically persist back to the database. The issue is you then pass the non attached User object from the initial request which does not have the ID, so the system thinks you are trying to create a new user, but it fails since there is now a duplicate login. I think to make this work you just need to remove the `userService.createUser(user)` call and annotate the `updateUser` controller method with `@Transactional`. You should make the method public as well.

Having said that, ALex's suggestion of making an upsert service method is a good idea and then you can move the `@Transactional` annotation to that method and keep the transaction boundary in your service and out of the controller.